# How to get models confidence in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I took pretrained model and trained it on custom dataset with 3 classes and softmax activation as an output layer. I got 91% accuracy on test set, but here's the problem. I want to my CNN to be able to say "I don't know what's on image". That will help with 2 issues:

- Missclassification
- Images without any class. I search for snakes on image and want to be able to say that there are no snakes on the image

I got strange results with softmax:

```
[[0.05 0.89 0.05]]
[[0.05 0.89 0.05]]
```

First image was second class, so model got it right, but second image has NO known class, but model is pretty certain there is. How can I get something closer to real probabilities?
And model isn't bad at classifying, it just always get something like 0.85-0.89

My first thought was to add another class with no snakes on image. But that's pretty dirty solution.
Can Detection/segmentation help here?

Comment: One can look into bayesian neural networks. They give insight into the model's uncertainty, in a way that standard neural networks cannot.

Comment: Yes for this you need to use a model with proper uncertainty quantification, like a Bayesian Neural Network.

Comment: here is an [example of a bayesian neural network to classify MNIST](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/bayesian_neural_network.py). it is implemented in tensorflow-probability.

Comment: Note that this is not a programming problem, it would be better suited for the AI stack exchange.

Comment: Didn't know about AI stack exchange, but now do, thanks.
And trying to get deeper in Bayesian Neural Networks, that seems to be what I need

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly well-known in the literature that most CNNs do not output *well-calibrated probabilities*: in other words the 'probability' output of the softmax often does not correlate well to the true likelihood of being correct. See, for example, [*On Calibration of Modern Neural Networks*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04599.pdf) by Guo et al for some context on the issue.

Recently interest has grown in *Bayesian deep learning* techniques which can model the *epistemic uncertainty*, i.e. the uncertainty in the model itself, and there are lots of interesting papers you can read, for example Kendall and Gal's [*What Uncertainties Do We Need in Bayesian Deep Learning for Computer Vision?*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04977.pdf) (there are also some slides from Kendall which are a bit lighter to read [here](https://alexgkendall.com/media/presentations/oxford_seminar.pdf)).

You could try the temperature scaling technique in Guo et al, which seems to improve the predictions somewhat.

Comment: Seems like model should be written with tfp layers in it? So, I just can not use that model, I need to change it's architecture or write a NN from ground up?